# Error on serialization with an "in" modifier in constructor

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I can't figure out why a serialization of such a sample class should fail:

```
using System.Text.Json;

class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(in double t)
    {
        this.Temperature = t;
    }

    public double Temperature { get; set; }
}

MyClass c = new(123);
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(c);    //throws here
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

The exception says:

> System.ArgumentException: The type 'System.Double&' may not be used as a type argument.

The problem seems related to the `in`-modifier, because by removing it the serializazion succeeds.

Any clue on why that's not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the serializer is looking for constructors that match the expected features, and either

1. fails to find a matching `MyClass(double)` constructor that it is looking for and gives up, or
2. finds the `MyClass(ref double)` constructor (which is what `in` ultimately is, just with some attributes), fails to check whether it is a by-ref, and emits the wrong IL

If you get a critical JIT failure, it is probably "2", otherwise "1".

But ultimately: this `in` almost certainly isn't really helping you any, unless you're on x86 *and even then* it is questionable whether it is actually helping anyway (I'd need receipts to be convinced). So maybe just don't use `in` here? All you're doing is deferring a dereference, which *might* actually **increase** the work done in many cases, if it means that instead of just using an ambient value already in the correct location on the stack, it needs to do a `stloc`+`ldloca` to get the address of a stack-local. This includes when using values from *properties* (if we assume that you don't have ref-return-type getters, which seems unlikely) - since `new MyClass(obj.SomeProp)` can't use the `in` directly, unless you get lucky and the JIT undoes all the indirection.

[We can see this in sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwDcBDKAAgmACsyBeMgOxgHcyAxCCMgbzIGUIAWxgAFKBAAOdMigBMZAL4BuALAAoEuRK5pTVgFkAngGFcxAM7mAFJSoA6AcLGSAlKrUABAIx3vATittOwAVGEEJGChiDABXWDd1dQ95Di5udTJMsg8AZjIAEwgY4FwYfiFRcSluAHMYDCVzeqUFLPUFJPkjUwtzdXS1LOy87rNLK0Li0rIMFwysgaGhjAALbHMQsIio2NhpBvnMjrVD4YKikrLQ8MjouLLeOoayJufjhSA===); with the `in`, the property-fetch thru constructor is:

```
IL_0014: callvirt instance float64 Foo::get_SomeProp()
IL_0019: stloc.0
IL_001a: ldloca.s 0
IL_001c: newobj instance void MyClass::.ctor(float64&)
```

and without the `in`, it is:

```
IL_0014: callvirt instance float64 Foo::get_SomeProp()
IL_0019: newobj instance void MyClass::.ctor(float64)
```

(again, the JIT may or may not "fix" this, depending on context)

Comment: Thanks Mark, the real case has a more complex struct than a simple double. I do live even without the "in" in my app, but I thought a reference would have better impact than copying the whole structure.

Comment: @MarioVernari and that certainly becomes true for large structs; just: `double` isn't large - it is the same size as an x64 reference, hence no benefit; if your actual struct is significantly bigger then yes: that's exactly when `in` becomes useful, but note: the value-type should also be `readonly` (i.e. `readonly struct`), otherwise the compiler has to add defensive copies when calling methods (including property getters, but not direct field access).

Comment: Well, mine isn't that "complex": just a couple of strings, so probably I'm at borderline. And yes, that's a readonly struct. Thank you for the lessons, though.